# Scraping site missing data

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So I'm trying to scrape the open positions on this site and when I use any type of requests (currently trying request-html) it doesn't show everything that's in the HTML.

```
# Import libraries
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://germanamerican.csod.com/ux/ats/careersite/5/home?c=germanamerican'

session = HTMLSession()

# Connect to the URL
response = session.get(url)

response.html.render()

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object¶
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")  

b = soup.findAll('a')
```

Not sure where to go. Originally thought the problem was due to javascript rendering but this is not working.

Comment: Are you interested in the 'Current Openings'?

Comment: What is the status code of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the initial GET doesn't get the data (which I assume is the job listings), and the js that does do that, uses a POST with a authorization token in the header. You need to get this token and then make the POST to get the data.

This token appears to be dynamic so we're going to get a little wonky getting it, but doable.

```
url0=r'https://germanamerican.csod.com/ux/ats/careersite/5/home?c=germanamerican'
url=r'https://germanamerican.csod.com/services/x/career-site/v1/search'

s=HTMLSession()
r=s.get(url0)
print(r.status_code)
r.html.render()

soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')

scripts=soup.find_all('script')

for script in scripts:
    if 'csod.context=' in script.text: x=script

j=json.loads(x.text.replace('csod.context=','').replace(';',''))


payload={
    'careerSiteId': 5,
    'cities': [],
    'countryCodes': [],
    'cultureId': 1,
    'cultureName': "en-US",
    'customFieldCheckboxKeys': [],
    'customFieldDropdowns': [],
    'customFieldRadios': [],
    'pageNumber': 1,
    'pageSize': 25,
    'placeID': "",
    'postingsWithinDays': None,
    'radius': None,
    'searchText': "",
    'states': []
}

headers={
    'accept': 'application/json; q=1.0, text/*; q=0.8, */*; q=0.1',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'authorization': 'Bearer '+j['token'],
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-length': '272',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'csod-accept-language': 'en-US',
    'origin': 'https://germanamerican.csod.com',
    'referer': 'https://germanamerican.csod.com/ux/ats/careersite/5/home?c=germanamerican',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

r=s.post(url,headers=headers,json=payload)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

the `r.json()` thats printed out is a nice json format version of the table of job listings.

Comment: Where did you get the payload and the headers from? I for the most part understand what you're saying.

Comment: @SamuelKhong inspecting the requests that my browser made when i went to the site.

Comment: Hi I have one more question on this. So I want to scrape one of the links within the links. e.g. https://germanamerican.csod.com/ux/ats/careersite/5/home/requisition/499?c=germanamerican

Comment: I'm really new with html requests so struggling a bit x-x

Comment: @SamuelKhong which part of that link are you after?

Comment: I'm trying to get the job description. So everything from the job title to the address on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to scrape that website with Requests.
I would suggest using Selenium or Scrapy.

Comment: he's using requests-html

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO!

Unfortunately, you won't be able to scrape that page with `requests` (nor `requests_html` or similar libraries) because you need a tool to handle dynamic pages - i.e., javascript-based.

With python, I would strongly suggest `selenium` and its `webdriver`. Below a piece of code that prints the desired output - i.e., all listed jobs (NB it requires `selenium` and Firefox webdriver to be installed and with the correct PATH to run)

```
# Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://germanamerican.csod.com/ux/ats/careersite/5/home?c=germanamerican'

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # initialize the webdriver. I use FF, might be Chromium or else

browser.get(url) # go to the desired page. You might want to wait a bit in case of slow connection
page = browser.page_source # this is the page source, now full with the listings that have been uploaded
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
jobs = soup.findAll('a', {'data-tag' : 'displayJobTitle'})
for j in jobs:
    print(j.text)

browser.quit()
```

Comment: requests_html does handle dynamic pages